# javascript compatibility chrome, safari, and opera on string search

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, safari, opera

I am doing my first javascript application and I have noticed that it only works in firefox (I cannot test IE).
I have created this software just to do some practice, in few words it allows to search for a given word in a given text, and renders on a div block, the original text highlighting the word searched (if it exists) and also tells the amount of times the word was found.

The variable **string** is the text where the search is going to be done, the variable **target** is the word to search, the variable **result** is where the result of the search within **string** is stored.

*The problem that I experience is that while in Firefox the code works perfectly finding every single time the word exists in the text, in the other browsers (based on webkit?) it only finds the word once.*

Here's the javaScript code:

```
function wordFinder() {
    'use strict';
    var string = document.getElementById('paste').value,
        target = document.getElementById('target').value,
        result =  string.match(target, 'g'),
        marked = string.replace(target, '<span class="found">' + target + '</span>', 'g');
    if (result === null) {
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Your word was not found in the content';
        document.getElementById('string').innerHTML = '<h2 align="center">No results to display</h2>';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = ('The word ' + target + ' was found ' + result.length + ' times.');
        document.getElementById('string').innerHTML = marked;
    }
}
```

and here's the HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Word finder</h2>
    <form name="finder" action="wordFinder" method="post">
        Paste the text you want to search within:<br>
        <textarea name="text" rows="10" cols="100" id="paste"></textarea><br>
        Paste the word you want to search:<br>
        <input name="search" type="text" id="target"/>
        <br><button type="button" onclick="wordFinder()">Search.</button>
    </form>
    <h4 id="result"></h4>
    <div id="style" class="layout"><p id="string">Results will appear here</p></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0):

This line is treated differently:

```
result = string.match(target, 'g'),
```

Note that `string.match` takes a single `RegExp` argument (see [ES5.1 spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.10)). You pass two arguments, which means that the first is taken as the RegExp, meaning it'll not give you a global match unless `target` is something like `/foo/g`. You can create the `RegExp` object yourself to make it match globally:

```
result = string.match(new RegExp(target, 'g')),
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wfcuxdye/).

I tested Opera 12 (presto), Opera 26, IE11 and Chrome 40, and they all behave the same way, giving a single match for your original code, only Firefox behaved differently - seemingly in violation of the EcmaScript 5.1 specification.

Comment: Hi, thanks, now it works. I only have one issue (as this concept is not very clear to me yet). The span with the 'found' class only works on the first word and the remaining ones are not marked. :)